# How can I select part of sqlite database using python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a very big database and I want to send part of that database (1/1000) to someone I am collaborating with to perform test runs. How can I (a) select 1/1000 of the total rows (or something similar) and (b) save the selection as a new .db file.

This is my current code, but I am stuck.

```
import sqlite3
import json
from pprint import pprint

conn = sqlite3.connect('C:/data/responses.db')       
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM responses;")
```

Comment: One option is to just copy the database file, open it and delete 999/1000th of the data and then send that copy to your collaborator. e.g. `DELETE FROM responses WHERE id > 100` or similar

Comment: Thanks - this generates a new file (responses.db-journal), but does not seem to affect the size of the original responses.db file. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does it matter which 1/1000th of the data you take?

Answer (score 0):

Create a another database with similar table structure as the original db. Sample records from original database and insert into new data base

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("responses.db")
sample_conn = sqlite3.connect("responses_sample.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c_sample = sample_conn.cursor()

rows = c.execute("select no, nm from responses")
sample_rows = [r for i, r in enumerate(rows) if i%10 == 0] # select 1/1000 rows

# create sample table with similar structure
c_sample.execute("create table responses(no int, nm varchar(100))")
for r in sample_rows:
    c_sample.execute("insert into responses (no, nm) values ({}, '{}')".format(*r))

c_sample.close()
sample_conn.commit()
sample_conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do this would be:

1. Copy the database file in your filesystem same as you would any other file (e.g. ctrl+c then ctrl+v in windows to make `responses-partial.db` or something)
2. Then open this new copy in an sqlite editor such as http://sqlitebrowser.org/ run the delete query to remove however many rows you want to. Then you might want to run compact database from file menu.
3. Close sqlite editor and confirm file size is smaller
4. Email the copy

Unless you need to create a repeatable system I wouldn't bother with doing this in python.  But you could perform similar steps in python (copy the file, open it it run delete query, etc) if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to

1. make a copy of the database file;
2. delete 999/1000th of the data, either by keeping the first few rows:

   ```sql
   DELETE FROM responses WHERE SomeID > 1000;
   ```

   or, if you want really random samples:

   ```sql
   DELETE FROM responses
   WHERE rowid NOT IN (SELECT rowid
                       FROM responses
                       ORDER BY random()
                       LIMIT (SELECT count(*)/1000 FROM responses));
   ```
3. run [VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) to reduce the file size.